# Get unique instance of types inheriting from base class with StructureMap

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have a bunch of services for which I always want to get a unique instance with StructureMap. Now, I can get this working by configuring each type like:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
  ...

  x.For<UserService>().AlwaysUnique();

  ...
});
```

But I don't really want to do that for every service type. The service types all inherit from `ServiceBase` - is there any way to configure StructureMap to use `AlwaysUnique()` for all types that inherit from `ServiceBase`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to create a convention to achieve this:

```
using StructureMap.Pipeline;
using StructureMap.TypeRules;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;

public class ConcreteLifecycleConvention : StructureMap.Graph.IRegistrationConvention
{
    private readonly Type _baseType;
    private readonly ILifecycle _lifecycle;

    public ConcreteLifecycleConvention(Type baseType, ILifecycle lifecycle)
    {
        _baseType = baseType;
        _lifecycle = lifecycle;
    }

    public void ScanTypes(TypeSet types, Registry registry)
    {
        foreach(var type in types.AllTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsAbstract || !type.CanBeCreated() || !type.CanBeCastTo(_baseType))
                continue;

            registry.For(type).LifecycleIs(_lifecycle);
        }
    }
}
```

Apply the convention in a scan:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(c =>
{
    c.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
        scan.With(new ConcreteLifecycleConvention(typeof(ServiceBase), 
            new UniquePerRequestLifecycle()));
    });
});
```

As a side note. With the built in conventions you can use the `OnAddedPluginTypes` to specify the lifecycle, but there is no built in convention that registers the concretes that is registered without an interface

```
scan.WithDefaultConventions().OnAddedPluginTypes(x => 
    x.LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle()));
```